# Get Closest tr html excluding last td

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

I have an `html` table with some html like:

```
<tr>

 <td>A</td>
 <td>B</td>
 <td>C</td>
 <td style="width: 10%">
  <img src="sign-add.png" alt="Add Member" id="img_123" data-id="123" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Add Member" />
 </td>
</tr>
```

On image click I want to get `closest` tr html but `last` td (i.e td with image)
should be excluded and `<tr>` tags should be included.It means html `output` should be like this:

```
<tr>
 <td>A</td>
 <td>B</td>
 <td>C</td>     
</tr>
```

I have tried this:

```
 $("#img_" + empCode).closest("tr").html();
```

but doesn't fullfill my requirements.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```js
var empCode = 123
var html = $("#img_" + empCode).closest("tr").clone().find('td:last').remove().end().prop('outerHTML');

snippet.log(html)
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
    <td>C</td>
    <td style="width: 10%">
      <img src="sign-add.png" alt="Add Member" id="img_123" data-id="123" style="cursor:pointer;" title="Add Member" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks @Johny..I was expecting you to answer ..;)